# java.sql.SQLException: Oracle Error ORA-12650DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 1,265

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, oracle12c, thin-client

I have a WAS 6.1 version insallted and it is using Java 1.5. Recently we have updated the database to Oracle 12c. 
    When I try to connect to the 12c Data source Im getting the error

```
"java.sql.SQLException: Oracle Error ORA-12650DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 1,265"


**

 - Steps that I have tried:

**
1- using ojdbc5.jar(already tried ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc6.jar bith of them not working

2-Set the custom properties 
   prop.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", "REQUIRED");
   prop.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "( DES40 )");
   prop.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client", "REQUESTED");
   prop.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client", "( MD5 )");

3- I am using a thin client and 
**jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:servicename** 

I havetried the below thin client address also

**jdbc:oracle:thin:/hostname:port:/servicename** 

Please help me to fix this issue. My Lincence to Oracle 12c will end on 13th Feb 2017. I know it's too late but please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Date:10-Feb-2017
```

Comment: Probably your db is configured to require some kind of encryption, and it is not consistent with client configuration. Try to disable integrity and encryption on the server side, check [Configuring Network Data Encryption and Integrity](http://oracle.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/network.121/e17607/asoconfg.htm) for more details.

Comment: Does anyone know hwich version of oci driver i have to use if i need to connect to a 12c databse from WAS6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c is not a supported database for WebSphere Application Server v6.1.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007624

Please upgrade to later version of WebSphere Application Server.